# Celery / Celery beat stuck on old version of a script

Tags: django, amazon-ec2, redis, django-celery, celerybeat

I've got a django application running on AWS EC2 using Celery for periodic updates. I recently had to update a data processing script on the Django app, but no matter what I seem to try, Celery continues to use old copies of the processing script.

Here's a run down:

- There was a change in how the data was published starting April 12. So the old processor stopped working on any data after April 12.
- I amended the script to work on all the data both up to and after April 12 and merged the changes to production.
- GitHub Actions ran successfully, built the containers, and deployed them to EC2.
- If I ssh into the EC2 instance and enter the container, I can run the `manage.py update_nameofmydatamodel` command and it runs properly and updates all of the data properly (I can tell because this feeds a website viz that then properly updates)
- When Celery Beat runs overnight, the data reverts to processing ONLY up to April 12 (I can tell because I go to the website viz and it has reverted back to only having data up to April 12)
- I removed the data model from the list of models to update through Celery Beat until I could figure out where the issue was coming from. But...it is STILL RUNNING the update!

Here are all the things I've tried:

- Celery is using a redis:alpine cache, I tried clearing the cache using `FLUSHALL` and `FLUSH SCRIPTS`
- I ran `celery -A projectName purge` and got a message that 0 messages were purged from the queue
- I fully removed the celery, celery beat, and redis containers and then pushed the latest versions onto EC2 again
- I stopped all the containers and restarted them (web, nginx, celery, beat, redis); I confirmed when the containers had stopped that all the celery processes were stopped also
- I stopped the EC2 instance entirely and restarted it

What am I missing in terms of where celery could be caching scripts or where a zombie process could be running? I am by no means a Django expert and inherited the deployment of this project, so I'm hoping I'm just missing something obvious at this point.

Thanks in advance for any ideas.

Comment: I am currently facing this issue, updated script and it's running the old version. Mine had to do with django celery and scrapy. Is this a cache issue?

Comment: I ended up running updates on the EC2 instance and it finally resolved. I couldn't ever determine an actual explanation, although I've found several instances of people running into similar problems.